# Cocoa - Parse a JSON string

Tags: json, cocoa, nsjsonserialization

I know that the web is full of examples about this, but I've tried everything, and I'm missing something. I want to parse a JSON string into a dicionary.

E have this response of the server:

```
{"type":"response", "action":"mkac", "result":"[{"Band":"Adele","Hits":422},{"Band":"Bryan Adams","Hits":93},{"Band":"Adai","Hits":30},{"Band":"Adamo","Hits":18},{"Band":"Adelle","Hits":15}]"}
```

And I make:

```
NSError *parseError = nil;
                        NSDictionary *outputDictionary = 
                        [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [output dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                        options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error: &parseError];
                        NSLog(@"server said: %@", [outputDictionary objectForKey:@"result"]);
```

But the outputDictionary allways gives me null.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: hmmm... wouldn't it be nice if there was an error returned by "`JSONObjectWithData`" that you could check to see what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Seems legit. The error is: "2012-10-03 15:05:35.207 IOSapp Lite[43330:f803] sparseError: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Badly formed object around character 50.) UserInfo=0xb53e4d0 {NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 50.}"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your json is malformed.  If you format it properly, you'll see why:

```
{
  "type":"response", 
  "action":"mkac", 
  "result":"[{"Band":"Adele","Hits":422},{"Band":"Bryan Adams","Hits":93},{"Band":"Adai","Hits":30},{"Band":"Adamo","Hits":18},{"Band":"Adelle","Hits":15}]"
}
```

You'll notice that the value for `"result"` starts with a `"` character, which means that the value is technically `"[{"`.  However after that, it comes across `Band`.  Since `Band` isn't surrounded in double quotes (or preceded by a `,` or a `}`, etc), it generates a parse error.  If you remove the double quote immediately before `[{` and immediately after `}]`, then it parses correctly:

```
{
  "type":"response", 
  "action":"mkac", 
  "result":[
    {
      "Band":"Adele",
      "Hits":422
    },
    {
      "Band":"Bryan Adams",
      "Hits":93
    },
    {
      "Band":"Adai",
      "Hits":30
    },
    {
      "Band":"Adamo",
      "Hits":18
    },
    {
      "Band":"Adelle",
      "Hits":15
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes I figured it out now. But thanks a lot for you answer! Small things gives us big problems :) ahah

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what happened. The json string was no valid, because of "[ that I had to replace with just [